# Problem with jquery code checkbox values takes as undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In the code shown below.... it should be able to fetch only the checkbox which is checked.. but it is taking the value as undefined....what is the problem in the code... and it displays all the checked and unchecked checbox table row contents

```
       for(k=1;k<=9000;k++)
        {   //each change
     $("#status"+k).live('click', function () {
        for(j=1;j<=k;j++)
     {
        alert (j);
            //var status = $("input[name=status]:checked").val();
                                            //alert(status);
            if ($('#status:checked').val() !== undefined) { 
                                            alert("false"); 
            var product_name = encodeURIComponent($('#product_name'+j).val());      
            var barcode = encodeURIComponent($('#barcode'+j).val());
            var Quantity = encodeURIComponent($('#Quantity'+j).val());
            var cart=product_name + barcode + Quantity;
                    alert(cart);
                        } else {
                    alert("true");  
            } 

        $('#cart1').val(cart);  
     }

    });

}
```

Comment: Clean your code. remove redundant spaces from the beggining.

Comment: Can't you create a generic class to bind the clicks instead of looping over it 9000 times?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#status').is(':checked')) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($(this).is(':checked')) {
```

In place of: if ($('#status:checked').val() !== undefined) {

I also suggest you to use jQuery .delegate() to get rid of that loop.
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/